# Angular 9: can't create a new project

Tags: angular

Totally new to Angular I'm trying to create a new project (my first Angular project) but no success, I'm systematically getting this error:

```
⠸ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fpezzati/.npm/_logs/2020-03-15T11_33_00_358Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Npm version is `6.14.2`, Node version is 12.6.1 and Angular is 9.0.6. I've already tried to update the `@angular/cli` to latest. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
Here is the command I use to create my project:

```
fpezzati@oem-OMEN-by-HP-Laptop-15-ce0xx microfrontend (feature/team-gwt) $ ng new team-alpha
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE team-alpha/README.md (1026 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/angular.json (3599 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/package.json (1287 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/tsconfig.json (489 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/tslint.json (1953 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/karma.conf.js (1022 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/tsconfig.app.json (210 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/index.html (295 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/polyfills.ts (2835 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/app/app.component.html (25723 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (954 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/src/app/app.component.ts (214 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (643 bytes)
CREATE team-alpha/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
⠴ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...tkMw1KLAXCawu1JtqI\n5'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fpezzati/.npm/_logs/2020-03-15T12_41_21_714Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

And this is the `package.json` as result of the failed `ng new`:

```
    {
  "name": "team-alpha",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever installed request package globally? It's problem with that package

Comment: How did you install angular-cli?

Comment: Request package has been deprecated you should reinstall your angular/cli globally to get it works https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: yes, @angular/cli is installed globally: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.

Comment: post the whole output incl the line how you create a new project. also check if a package.json is present in your current directory

Comment: [Try this Answer Link for resolving this issue][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455400/10538842

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to run ng serve succesfully. Maybe there is a better way to solve this but, here is what I do:
- I update the `codelyzer` dependency from `^5.1.2` to `5.2.1` in my `package.json`,
- I run `npm cache clean --force`,
- run `npm install`.

Then launching `ng serve` the angular starting page shows up.

Comment: Following worked for me: deleted `node_modules` folder, in `package.json` updated `codelyzer` to `5.2.1`, and then ran `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

I run through the same issue,check the folder size while the terminal is installing every couple of minutes, if the folder size is increasing it means everything is fine, the initial project size is 340 MB, it will take time, it seems like it is stuck but again it is just a poor representation  of the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Delete node_module folder first and do "npm install"
then try to create a project again..!

Answer (score 0):

For me, what works is updating the package `"codelyzer` to the latest version which is currently `"5.2.1"`.

Then I run `npm install`.

Comment: Hello! That was just what I did but, isn't that just a bit hackish?  Do you know there is a cleaner way to solve the issue? TIA.